# Add ribbon button for Outlook addin in calender-view

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, ribbonx

Is it possible to add a ribbon button in calender-view for Outlook when an appoinment is selected? Creating a addin with javascript (yo generated)Like the Teams addin does [Button in calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSWt4.png)

I have search but couldn't find any example of this. Right now I have 2 buttons when openingn an appointment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

When creating or viewing an appointment or meeting as the organizer, add-in commands added to the default tab appear on the Meeting, Meeting Occurrence, Meeting Series, or Appointment tabs on pop-out forms. However, if the user selects an item in the calendar but doesn't open the pop-out, the add-in's ribbon group won't be visible in the ribbon.

When viewing a meeting as an attendee, add-in commands added to the default tab appear on the Meeting, Meeting Occurrence, or Meeting Series tabs on pop-out forms. However, if a user selects an item in the calendar but doesn't open the pop-out, the add-in's ribbon group won't be visible in the ribbon.

See [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook?tabs=xmlmanifest) for more information.

Comment: Very detailed answer! But, I'm still wondering the exact answer to the OP Q `Is it possible to add a ribbon button in calender-view for Outlook when an appoinment is selected?`

Comment: No, it is not possible now.